# Find dw in terms of all the variables: $\frac{1}{w} = \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v}$

Tags: calculus

So I understand how to find the differential of an explicit function $w = w(t,u,v): dw = \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial w}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial w}{\partial v}dv$. How do I find it for implicitly defined functions?

As a side note, I know $dw \neq \Delta w$; instead, I view dw as the limit of $\Delta w$ when the independent variables, $dt = \Delta t, du = \Delta u, dv = \Delta v$ tend to zero. This is correct, right?

Comment: $$d\left(\frac{1}{w}\right) = -\frac{dw}{w^2}$$ Substitute for $w$ and isolated $dw$. This technique will work for all invertible implicit functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do $w=\left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1}$, then
$$dw=\frac{\partial\left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1}}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial\left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1}}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial\left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1}}{\partial v}dv.$$

Comment: you can make explicit for the other variables for example $$t=\left(\frac{1}{w}-\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1},$$ and do the same for $dt$